# Recover bitmap file from FileOutputStream in a fragment

Tags: android, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

Im trying to capture image and then for good practice I put bitmap file in the the `FileOutputStream` how can I recover the bitmap using the filename.

**Activity**

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA && data != null){

            fragment = null;
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            String filename = "bitmap.png";

            try {
                FileOutputStream stream = this.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                assert bmp != null;
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream);

                stream.close();
                bmp.recycle();

                fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.fade_out,R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.slide_out_right);

                fragment =FragmentCropper.newInstance(filename);
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer,fragment,Constant.BackStackTag.CROP_TAG);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(Constant.BackStackTag.CROP_TAG);

                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**In the Fragment**

How to recover the Bitmap using the filename

```
 try {
     //FileInputStream stream = getActivity().openFileInput(filename);
     //mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
     //stream.close();

     String path = "path/"+filename;
     mBitmap = BitmapUtils.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(path,500,500);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (mBitmap.isRecycled())
            mBitmap.recycle();
        mBitmap=null;
    }
```

Comment: Im having problem getting the file in the FileOutputSteam

Comment: I use inputsteam before but the bitmap is scaled down

Comment: I want to get the original bitmap

Comment: its just a function for decoding bitmap

Comment: If you use `FileOutputStream stream = this.openFileOutput(filename,....)` to write then use the reverse to read: `FileInputStream stream = this.openFileInput(filename);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String path = "path/"+filename;
```

Change to

```
String path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + filename;
```

Comment: Thanks now I know that both the FileInputSteam and this solution work the same. And why is it that the bitmap was resized when I put it in the imageview in the fragment is this because of the compression?